# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (16,3,3,3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, caffe

I am trying to convert a caffe model to tensorflow model using [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/dhaase-de/caffe-tensorflow-python3).

I am getting the below error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (16,3,3,3)'

method which throws the error:

```
    def normalize_pb_data(self, layer):
        transformed = []
        for blob in layer.blobs:
            print('layer name - %s %d' % (layer.name,len(blob.shape.dim)) )
            if len(blob.shape.dim):
                dims = blob.shape.dim
                c_o, c_i, h, w = map(int, [1] * (4 - len(dims)) + list(dims))
            else:
                c_o = blob.num
                c_i = blob.channels
                h = blob.height
                w = blob.width
            if layer.name != "data/bias":
                data = numpy.array(blob.data, dtype=np.float32).reshape(c_o, c_i, h, w)
                transformed.append(data)
        return transformed
```

Layer info from prototext:

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data/bias"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    bias_term: true
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 1
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
    dilation: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to start by looking into "blob.data". It seems to be a 0-dimensional array which obviously cannot be reshaped to more dimensions.